# app dont appear when device is unlocked

Tags: android

I just create a simple android project to show in a textview a text written in a edit view when a button is clicked.

The issue is that when I click to run the app, I select the available virtual device and then "ok", the emulator starts, I unlock the device but the app dont appear. Do you know why?

The code is here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        EditText input_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = input_text.getText().toString();
        tview.setText(message);
    }
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.ricardorei.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4000002"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"


             />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The emulator could be a bit slow, you should check the Android Studio, maybe it was still being deployed to the emulator, they are generally slower.

Comment: Look at the Run tab (in the bottom close to logcat), may you are getting an error there.

Comment: Thanks, it just appears launching app without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do to track this:

1-check whether the gradle successfully build the app.

2-keep track of stop button on toolbar what it indicates.

3-check logs for possible errors.